# Show custom length excerpt on only search results page WP

Tags: wordpress, search

I have a search results page and would like to show longer results then the standard excerpt length in WP (which is 55 words).

Here's my code so far, which I added to functions.php

```
<?php if (is_search()) {

function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 400;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
} ?>
```

I expected that the conditional statement would cause the excepts to show longer now. But this does not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the if statement in the function

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    if (is_search()) {
        return 400;
    }
    else{
        return $length;
    }
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Comment: Thanks @Moishy, offcourse the if statement should be IN the function :) rookie mistake :) (which I still am).